# Error:: [$injector:unpr] when trying to setup routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, angularjs-routing

Trying to setup a simple authentication for my angularjs app. When I debug the app.js in line 20 I receive this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=configProvider%20%3C-%20config
```

Anyone have any idea what is goin wrong here?

here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/k0dfl8ZFSCpYEBhuZMBf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great place to start with these kinds of issues is to use the un-minified version of Angular (angular.js instead of angular.min.js).  Then you get this slightly more readable error message:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: configProvider <- config
```

That lead us to your navbarController.js where you're injecting the service `config` which hasn't been defined (thus the "Unknown provider" error):

```
var NavbarController = function ($scope, $location, config, authService) {
```

...

```
NavbarController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'config', 'authService'];
```